# ESDoc with TypeScript: how to use comment blocks?

Tags: typescript, esdoc

I use [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org/) to generate a documentation for a JS project. It works well!
I now want to migrate this JS project into a TS project. For the documentation, I saw [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esdoc-typescript-plugin) to help ESDoc handle TypeScript.

It kinds of work. By simply using the plugin, the doc is generated like before, as seen below:

```
   /**
   * @desc Stringify a number
   * @param {number} nbr Number to stringify.
   * @return {string} The stringified number.
   * @example const str = stringify(42);
   */
  stringify(nbr: number): string {
    return `${nbr}`;
  }
```

[image: The documentation is well generated]

I find it's a bit awkward to define the types with TypeScript **and** inside the comment block. So, like [the documentation says](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esdoc-typescript-plugin#example), I've removed these types from the comments:

```
   /**
   * @desc Stringify a number
   * @param nbr Number to stringify.
   * @return The stringified number.
   * @example const str = stringify(42);
   */
  stringify(nbr: number): string {
    return `${nbr}`;
  }
```

But because of that, the generated documentation has lost the types. TypeScript's types are not taken into account:

[image: Types are lost]

Funny thing, if I remove the tag `@desc` (and just the tag, not the corresponding text) like below, the results are also different:

```
   /**
   * Stringify a number
   * @param nbr Number to stringify.
   * @return The stringified number.
   * @example const str = stringify(42);
   */
  stringify(nbr: number): string {
    return `${nbr}`;
  }
```

[image: Lot of information are missing]

This time, TypeScript's types are taken into account, but I've lost `@param` and `@return` descriptions and even the `@example`!

I must say I'm running out of ideas...

**Do you know how can I take advantages of TypesScript's types without losing the rest of the documentation?**

According to [the documentation of esdoc-typescript-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esdoc-typescript-plugin#example), it's possible, but I can't manage to do that.
What am I doing wrong? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The plugin has been abandoned for 3 years now, and it still says it's only a PoC. Have you managed to make it work or find an alternative?

Comment: @Papooch unfortunately not, I just gave up :/